# Python substitute variable in SQL query

Tags: python, sql, variables, substitution

I am using Python3 and connecting to Impala DB using impala package as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd
from impala.dbapi import connect
from impala.util import as_pandas
import sys

def pull_from_dw(dw_conn, qry,qryparams):
    cur = dw_conn.cursor()
    if (qryparams is None):
        cur.execute(qry)
    else:
        cur.execute(qry,qryparams)
    custdata=as_pandas(cur)
    return custdata

x = sys.argv[1]
query_str="select * from <table_name> where <column_name> = '{}';"
print(query_str)
dw_conn = connect(host='10.xxx.xx.xx', port=21050, use_ssl=True,
    user='<username>',
    password='<password>',
    auth_mechanism='LDAP')
df =  pull_from_dw(dw_conn,query_str,x)
print(df)
```

I can substitute directly by specifying .format(x) in the sql query. However, I need to variable substitution in the calling function df =  pull_from_dw(dw_conn,query_str,x) and getting error as below. Please assist:

> $ /usr/bin/python3 script1.py 'abc'
>
> impala.error.ProgrammingError: Query parameters argument should be a
>   list, tuple, or dict object

Comment: `<table_name> and <column_name>` have to be filled in with respective table and column names, that is incorrect sql syntax, also pls see to sql query syntax for things like `SELECT` etc....and same for setting up the host i.e the credentials how are those being setup?

Comment: yeah, host, table name and column name are correct. just dummied them for asking the question

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string to qryparams while it takes a list tuple or dictionary. pass it the following and It should fix your issue:

```
pull_from_dw(dw_conn, qry,[x])
```

Comment: Hi, I had changed to pull_from_dw(dw_conn, qry,[x]) and executed as below: $ /usr/bin/python3 script1.py 'abc'
select * from <table_name> where <column_name>  = '{}';
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [x, y, z]
Index: []